# I want to add a search button with a text box and a drop down for showing the resuls in itin my windows application using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

when entered a text in the text box and on pressing the the search button i should get the search results in the drop down box. The search button should get the result from webpage URL say http://in.finance.yahoo.com/actives?e=bo  and those matching results should be displayed in the drop down.
can anyone please help me with the logic behind it and what resources should be used. i am very beginner in development and C#.
thanks in advance. 
i hope i get the best results in my search box and for my Question.

Comment: girly polite: what have you tried? :-)

Comment: @Aniket - you could have asked politely!

Comment: @Aniket i have used the url "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=NTPC.NS+ONGC.NS&f=npob2m2wk1k2d1r2" to store data in csv file and then retrieve and store in the gridview. but i need to add search funtionality to the same window and show only the selected data into the gridview

Comment: Mohammad- You are using textbox to get the some data from Textbox right??? But you didn't use the text from Textbox with URL, and one more thing, what you are trying to achieve is the After Getting some results , you can try addinf items to combo Box  like this comboBox1.Items.Add();

Comment: You Want To Search in page and show result in a drop down list?you want to search according with column?and what do you want to show in drop down list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't Completely explain your goal,but if you want to search in your URL grid view you can do this:
I search according name filed in grid view:you can use simply a web browser for his:

```
 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnsearch.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://in.finance.yahoo.com/actives?e=bo");
        }

        private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (HtmlElement item in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td"))
            {
                if (item.GetAttribute("className").Equals("second name"))
                {
                    if (item.InnerText.Contains( txtsearch.Text))
                    {
                        lstresult.Items.Add(item.InnerText);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

with this lines of code you can search according name and show result in a list box